# Copy part of QString

Tags: qt

I have a QString. I need to create a copy of this QString. In Delphi this function  `copy`

```
function Copy ( Source : string; StartChar, Count : Integer ) : string;
```

I need the same in Qt.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at `QString::mid(int start, int length)` in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#mid).